# Finding the maximum number in a 2D vector

Tags: rust

Several people who work with Rust have said that if you find yourself using a lot of clones, you're probably doing something wrong. I'm trying to rewrite some code I wrote to find the maximum number in a 2D vector to use `RefCell`s for the inner vector due to the fact that (as much as I hate it) I need interior mutability on the 2D vec for my physics engine. However, all my code related to this now needs a ton of clone calls. I'm using the "maximum integer" part of my codebase just because its the shortest and easiest to explain piece. Here is my code:

```
let max_row = |row: &RefCell<Vec<Unit>>| -> Option<usize> {
    row.clone()
       .into_inner()
       .iter()
       .fold(None, |max, unit: &Unit| match max {
        None => Some(unit.tiles.len()),
        el @ Some(_) => {
            if el.unwrap() < unit.tiles.len() {
                Some(unit.tiles.len())
            } else {
                el
            }
        }
    })
};

// find the highest height in this list of rows. Same as above, but uses above. (:
let toplevel = world.map
                    .iter()
                    .fold(None, |max, vec| match max {
    None => max_row(vec),
    r @ Some(_) => {
        match max_row(vec) {
            None => r,
            z @ Some(_) => {
                if r.unwrap() < z.unwrap() { z } else { r }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is a tad ugly, but the worst part is the use of `.clone` and `.into_inner` right in a row after sending it as a pointer. For some reason, it just feels icky, probably because I did that as a fix, not how I originally was hoping it could turn out. I have only a mediocre understanding of borrowing, which could be the problem.

To clarify the code, here is Unit:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Unit {
  pub tiles: Vec<Tile>,
}

// And a basic version of Tile

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub enum Tile {
  Wall,
  Floor,
}
```

And world is just a `Vec<RefCell<Vec<Unit>>>`.

I really hope there is a better way, and if there is, could you explain it in such a way that I could apply it to other ugly areas of my codebase where this is also a problem? For instance, I have another area where I need to use a vector from inside a closure, but also need to modify it later, so in the closure I am cloning it, which seems like an ugly solution.

Comment: Please review your code and try to produce a compilable example. Trying to compile the code you've provided errors with *error: no field \`map\` on type \`std::vec::Vec<std::cell::RefCell<std::vec::Vec<Unit>>>\`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I start by walking through the code and improving it step-by-step, but this time I'll start with one piece of advice and showing my final solution. Read the [`Iterator` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) and commit the method names and a rough idea of what they do to memory!

```
let max = world.iter().flat_map(|r| {
    let r = r.borrow();
    r.iter().map(|unit| unit.tiles.len()).max()
}).max();
```

---

1. Instead of `match`ing, seeing if something is a `Some`, then `unwrap`ping it, just bind the pattern to a variable:

   ```
   match max {
       None => max_row(vec),
       Some(old_max) => {
           match max_row(vec) {
               None => Some(old_max),
               Some(new_max) => {
                   if old_max < new_max {
                       Some(new_max)
                   } else {
                       Some(old_max)
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Extract that `max_row` call to before the match, since it's done unconditionally.
3. Getting a default from an `Option` is a common pattern: `Option::unwrap_or` and `Option::unwrap_or_else`. Converting an `Option<T>` to another `Option<U>` , but only if it's `Some`, is also a common pattern: `Option::map` and `Option::and_then`. You should *also* memorize what capabilities `Option` and `Result` have.

   ```
   let mr = max_row(vec);
   max.map(|old_max| {
       match mr {
           None => Some(old_max),
           Some(new_max) => {
               if old_max < new_max {
                   Some(new_max)
               } else {
                   Some(old_max)
               }
           }
       }
   }).unwrap_or(mr)
   ```
4. Repeat.

   ```
   max.map(|old_max| {
       mr.map(|new_max| {
           if old_max < new_max {
               Some(new_max)
           } else {
               Some(old_max)
           }
       }).unwrap_or(Some(old_max))
   }).unwrap_or(mr)
   ```
5. `map(F).unwrap_or(D)` is also a common pattern: `Option::map_or`:

   ```
   max.map_or(mr, |old_max| {
       mr.map_or(Some(old_max), |new_max| {
           if old_max < new_max {
               Some(new_max)
           } else {
               Some(old_max)
           }
       })
   })
   ```
6. I don't know how to incrementally get out of this code. One possibility is to switch to a match statement to try and flatten some of the cases:

   ```
   match (max, max_row(vec)) {
       (None, new_max) => new_max,
       (Some(old_max), None) => Some(old_max),
       (Some(old_max), Some(new_max)) => {
           if new_max > old_max {
               Some(new_max)
           } else {
               Some(old_max)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
7. [`std::cmp::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/fn.max.html) exists, so I'd use that:

   ```
   match (max, max_row(vec)) {
       (None, new_max) => new_max,
       (Some(old_max), None) => Some(old_max),
       (Some(old_max), Some(new_max)) => Some(cmp::max(new_max, old_max)),
   }
   ```
8. Again, I don't know a way to incrementally get from here to iterator methods. This is why I encourage everyone to memorize what functions exist so that you can read the iterator documentation when you *know* there's something that solves a problem.